# Setting variables from textbox values in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, variables, textbox

Sort of new to objective-c, just wondering how I can set a variable as a value from a textbox. I'm setting up my login screen and will be using a JSON request to process the variables.

```
@interface LoginController : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet UITextField *txtUsername;
    IBOutlet UITextField *txtPassword;
    IBOutlet UIButton *btnLogin;
}

-(IBAction)btnLogin:(id)sender;


@end
```

Everything is defined  in the above .h

```
@implementation LoginController

-(IBAction)btnLogin:(id)sender
{
    username = [txtUsername];   
}
```

Just need to know the syntax to set that username variable to the text in the textbox when btnLogin is clicked. (.m file above)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the value of the text in the text field like so :

```
-(IBAction)btnLogin:(id)sender
{
    NSString * username = [txtUsername text];
}
```

also please to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextfield?language=objc#symbols) of the UITextField

Comment: Please if my answer helped you mark it as answer, the NSString is the type of the text property in the UITextField text

Comment: Yeah I will just gotta wait a few minutes